# How to handle response codes in RestTemplate without catching exceptions? [Spring Boot]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm sending a response to another web service to create an user. If the user already exists it sends back the 409 response. I'm using RestTemplate like so:

```
    @PostMapping("/todos/{toDoNoteId}/users")
    public ResponseEntity <String> postUser(@RequestBody User user, @PathVariable int toDoNoteId, UriComponentsBuilder builder)throws HttpMessageNotReadableException, ParseException{

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final String uri = "http://friend:5000/users";

        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, user, String.class); 
            return result;
        }
        catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(ex.getRawStatusCode()).headers(ex.getResponseHeaders())
                    .body(ex.getResponseBodyAsString());

        }
    }
```

While catching an exception somewhat works (in the catch block i can access the status code and body), is there a way to access it without exceptions something similar like this:

```
    @PostMapping("/todos/{toDoNoteId}/users")
    public ResponseEntity <String> postUser(@RequestBody User user, @PathVariable int toDoNoteId, UriComponentsBuilder builder)throws HttpMessageNotReadableException, ParseException{

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final String uri = "http://friend:5000/users";


            ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, user, String.class); 
            if(result.getStatusCode()=="409"){
            // do something
            }
            else{
            // do something else
            }
            return result;

   }
```

Comment: Digression: It's not a good way to call service through its host and port, I suggest you use Eureka, which provides Service Discovery feature, and it's easy to use it since you've used Spring Boot.

Comment: @troy Thank you for the suggestion, I will consider changing it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been check the ExceptionHandler? When exception throws, ExceptionHandler handles it.

For example:

```
@ControllerAdvice()
public class CustomExceptionHandler {
   private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("CustomExceptionHandler");

   @ExceptionHandler(YourException.class)
   public ResponseEntity handleYourException(HttpServletRequest request, YourException ex) {
       return ResponseEntity.ok("");
   }

   @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
   public ResponseEntity handleException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
       logExp("Exception", request, ex);
       //return new ResponseEntity<>();
       return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that as far as I understand if the postEntity gets the 409 code or other non sucess code it automaticaly throws an exception, without getting to the if clause.
Not sure how I could order the restTemplate to throw my created exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom resttemplate and define exception handler. Here is a code snippet.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomRestTemplate extends RestTemplate {
    @Autowired
    private CustomErrorHandler customErrorHandler;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.setErrorHandler(customErrorHandler);
    }
}


@Component
public class CustomErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
      if(response.getStatusCode() != "409"){
       return true;
      }else {
       return false;
      }
    }

   @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
      String responseBody = response.getBody();//Pls read from InputStream and create write into String


            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

            jsonObj.put("status", response.getStatusCode());
            jsonObj.put("body", responseBody );
            jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

            responseString = jsonArray.get(0).toString();


      throw new MyException(responseString );

   }

}

class MyException throw RuntimeException {
   public MyException (String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

So, your class will changed to

```
 @PostMapping("/todos/{toDoNoteId}/users")
    public ResponseEntity <String> postUser(@RequestBody User user, @PathVariable int toDoNoteId, UriComponentsBuilder builder)throws HttpMessageNotReadableException, ParseException{

        CustomRestTemplate restTemplate = new CustomRestTemplate ();
        final String uri = "http://friend:5000/users";

        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, user, String.class); 
        return result       
    }
```

Comment: The thing is I still want to return a ResponseEntity with the status code and body of the response that I got from the other service. Also, how could the exception look like and where would it be caught?

Comment: it will be return automatically. 
1) On successful remote call -> ```return result``` will make it for you
2) On Failure, throw your own exception in ```handleError ``` of ```CustomErrorHandler)```  method. A caller to ```postUser``` will get same

Comment: What would the exception need to return? Could you give me an example of how it should look like? I want it to return a body with statusCode and a message that I got from the other service.

Comment: _What would the exception need to return?_, you no need to return. Just throw exception. Spring will take care